# How to install latest stable release of PHP on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php5, ubuntu-14.04

I've installed PHP on Ubuntu14.04 as shown in [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/using-php5-fpm-with-apache2-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts) link. I currently have PHP 5.5.9 installed, but the current stable release is 5.5.12, is there any way to install current stable release on Ubuntu 14.04 ?

Comment: The simplest way would be to replace the PHP5.5.9 installation with a 5.5.12. It should be as simple as replacing the files be sure you backup the current installation.  Is there a reason you have to use 5.5.12 instead of 5.5.9 considering 5.5.12 has not been pushed for a reason?

Comment: @Ramhound It's not that trivial to "replace the files". You cannot just backup an existing PHP installation as it's scattered across the system. Moreover, going to the latest release is advised for security reasons and critical bug fixes.

Comment: Before moving on to do what @BigChris suggests, you should take a look at this post on StackOverflow where another user trying to precede you in your tracks is facing some, apparently yet unsolved, problems. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716053/php-5-5-12-configure-error-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 3):

Although http://www.dev-metal.com/how-to-setup-latest-version-of-php-5-5-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/ is for 12.04, the steps should be the same. It seems you may have to add a PPA to get the latest version. PHP.net shows 5.5.12 as the latest stable release with a 1st May 2014 date.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this page for a super-easy way of upgrading PHP to the latest version on 14.04 - http://www.dev-metal.com/install-setup-php-5-6-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

In short, you need to add the PHP 5.6 package created by Ondřej Surý to spt-get, then update and install php5. I've just done this myself and had no problems.